# Singular cohomology of schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, notation

In many places I see that people refer to $H^\ast(X;\mathbb{Z})$ for $X$ a scheme (a nice one, say projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$, etc.). What is meant by this? Surely it is not the singular cohomology of $X$, but rather the cohomolgy of the associated analytic space? Or does it refer to sheaf cohomology? Or how should it Interpret this when I see it? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give specific instances of use. It is most likely the singular cohomology ring of the analytification. Also, just a remark about the deleted post. It *is* true that the singular cohomology of a (locally contractible) space is the cohomology of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$. So, in particular, if $X/\mathbb{C}$ is some nice projective scheme, then $H^i_\text{sing}(X^\text{an},\mathbb{Z})=H^i(X^\text{an},\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$. Of course, as J. Huisman points out below, this surely must be done in the analytic topology else you evidently get zero.